# replace string in a loop

Tags: awk, sed, perl

I need to some strings in a file in the following fashion

Old file:

```
Real/Test1
Real/Test1
Real/Test2
Real/Test3
Real/Test3
Real/Test4
```

New File:

```
Real/Test1  a1 b1 c1 d1
Real/Test1  a1 b1 c1 d1
Real/Test2  a2 b2 c2 d2
Real/Test3  a3 b3 c3 d3
Real/Test3  a3 b3 c3 d3
Real/Test4  a4 b4 c4 d4
```

I have an intermediate file which has the old string in the column 1 and then the new string, something like this.

```
Test1 a1 b1 c1 d1
Test2 a2 b2 c2 d2
Test3 a3 b3 c3 d3
Test4 a4 b4 c4 d4
```

Could anyone please help with this?

With my very primitive knowledge, I tried following:

(while read n1 n2 
do set n1 n2 
sed -i "s/$n1/$n1 $n2/g" old > final 
done)

where "old" and "intermediate" inputs are the content mentioned above.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: SE is not a free coding service. I'm certain you tried something already, add that to your question.

Comment: Agree, let's see what you've tried already, see if we can collectively get you on the right track if it's not working quite right.

Comment: Thanks Grochmal and Steve for asking for the trial I am making. My scripting ability is very primitive and therefore I was hesitant putting my attempts here..So what I did is following:                                                                                                 (while read n1 n2
do
set n1 n2
sed -i "s/$n1/$n1 $n2/g" old > final
done)<intermediate                                                                                       where old is the old file as I wrote in my question and intermediate is the intermediate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -lne '
   @ARGV and $h{$1}=s/(\S+)//r,next;
   s|/(\S+)\K|$h{$1}|;print;
' intermediate.file old.file
```

---

### Results

```
Real/Test1 a1 b1 c1 d1
Real/Test1 a1 b1 c1 d1
Real/Test2 a2 b2 c2 d2
Real/Test3 a3 b3 c3 d3
Real/Test3 a3 b3 c3 d3
Real/Test4 a4 b4 c4 d4
```

---

### Explanation

- Using the intermediate file (@ARGV is > 0) we populate the hash using the first field as the key and the remaining fields as the corresponding value.
- When we process the old file (@ARGV = 0), we look at the string after the slash and use that to pullup the hash value and put it back in the current line.

Answer (score 2):

Since your files appear to be sorted in order of the join field, you could use the `join` command fairly easily e.g.

```
join old <(sed 's;^;Real/;' intermediate)
```

or (if your shell doesn't support process substitution)

```
sed 's;^;Real/;' intermediate | join old -
```

ex.

```
$ sed 's;^;Real/;' intermediate | join old -
Real/Test1 a1 b1 c1 d1
Real/Test1 a1 b1 c1 d1
Real/Test2 a2 b2 c2 d2
Real/Test3 a3 b3 c3 d3
Real/Test3 a3 b3 c3 d3
Real/Test4 a4 b4 c4 d4
```

Comment: Clever and naughty solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this with your gnu awk :

```
awk -F"[/ ]" 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2OFS$3OFS$4;next}$2 in a {print $0,a[$2]}'  intermediatefile oldfile >newfile
```

Comment: Thanks George, but this doesn't take care of repeated lines in the old file.

Comment: @ashu Yeah, right. Try the revised code. Mind that file read order has been reversed now.

Comment: Sorry, this is printing the old file.

Comment: @ashu I had a typo. Try again please. Sorry i am on the road and i can not test my proposal...

Comment: Thanks so much George, still one problem, spaces between columns 2-4 are lost, they come together.

Comment: @ashu Try `a[$1]=$2OFS$3OFS$4`